# prevent rails from escaping special characters in url param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, escaping

I have a request like the following:

/campaigns/info/2.json?query=campaign_info&resource=2&ts=1355348205&**sig=%2B%5Cx97%5Cx19D%5C%22%5Cx15%5B%5CxE7J%5CtyTiA*%3D%3A%2B%5CxCE'8q%5CxF9%20Fl%24B%5Cx8D%5Cx118%5Cr%25%5CxFC%5Cx98-%5CxA33%5CxF4%5Cx0F!w%24%5CxD6d4m%5Cx1D%5CxE5J%2B%5Ce%5Cx94%5B%5Cx88j%5Cx1A%5CxB8g%5Ca%5D0%3Bf**&api_key=7XFtqgcVROs17xOEcjum

When my rails server gets this request, it determines params[:sig] to be:

```
+\\x97\\x19D\\\"\\x15[\\xE7J\\tyTiA*=:+\\xCE'8q\\xF9 Fl$B\\x8D\\x118\\r%\\xFC\\x98-\\xA33\\xF4\\x0F!w$\\xD6d4m\\x1D\\xE5J+\\e\\x94[\\x88j\\x1A\\xB8g\\a]0;f
```

When I really want params[:sig] to be:

```
+\x97\x19D\"\x15[\xE7J\tyTiA*=:+\xCE'8q\xF9 Fl$B\x8D\x118\r%\xFC\x98-\xA33\xF4\x0F!w$\xD6d4m\x1D\xE5J+\e\x94[\x88j\x1A\xB8g\a]0;f
```

How do I get the second output?

Thanks.

Comment: Double backward slash is necessary due to historical reasons. So, it can't be avoided. But, it depends on your purpose of use. If you are only showing it on View, then it wouldn't show as double slashes. If somehow, it shows as such, then you can use html_safe to show in View. On the other hand, if you are using it for internal purposes i.e. Model or Controller, then there is no need to replace \\ with \ just for the purpose of showing.

Answer (score -1):

I finally did it with:

```
while str.gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ''); end
```

But because I only needed 0-9 and a-z. Hope this helps!